# Matching grades to names in separate sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm having some trouble with an excel formula. What I have in sheet A is a list of student names in (Fname LName) format, and then I have the same list of students in a separate sheet along with exam grades in an adjacent column (b). What I'm stuck on is trying to take all of the grades in the second sheet and match them in an adjacent column on the 1st sheet using a formula. The layout is shown below

```
Sheet A-                     Sheet B-
Names  Grades                Names     Grades
x                            x           1 
x                            x           2
x                            x           3 
x                            x           4
x                            x           5
x                            x           6
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As the answer below suggests, this is a perfect situation to use VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 2):

[Vlookup()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194701%28v=office.14%29.aspx) should work. With the Student names in column A, row 1 has the labels, start this formula in cell B2 and copy down

```
=vlookup(A2,SheetB!$A$1:$B$100,2,false)
```

This is on the assumption that the grades are listed on a sheet called SheetB. Adjust sheet names and ranges as required.